# What's a good website or book to learn Photoshop CS3 from?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Photoshop Tutorials?](https://superuser.com/questions/20077/photoshop-tutorials)

I'm looking to learn Photoshop CS3. I mean really master it. i can do some basic things, but I'm not familiar with workflow or keyboard shortcuts yet.

What are some good websites (and/or books) that teach concepts and skills, and don't simply walk you through creating a specific layout or image?

Please post links when possible. Websites may be videos or text-based.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Free content is better for me.

Comment: Do you mean CS4?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/20077/photoshop-tutorials

Comment: In future, please confirm that a question is not a duplicate before posting, as this is the purpose of the list of duplicate questions when posting a question. Duplicates will be closed, and continues duplicate posting can lead to suspension.

Comment: @ 8 Days of Malaise - Nope, CS3.

Comment: @Diago - That is for CS*4*, not CS*3*. Please find a CS3 duplicate or reopen. Thanks.

Comment: I have made the duplicate CW. Feel free to update it to be for both CS3 & CS4. However, I have checked the links and most of them include tutorials for both versions, as the changes between CS3 and CS4 was extremely small. A feature or version does **NOT** make a question any less a duplicate.

Comment: @Diago - Thanks. I will try to be more careful about dupes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/) has some of the most comprehensive video tutorials for Photoshop that I've come across. The only caveat is that they aren't free, but we can't have it all can we :)

Comment: Please in future ensure a question is not a duplicate, and vote to close as such. Especially questions you have already answered.